# How to pass complete row values from child to parent window using opener.document

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the below line to pass the value from child window to parent window

"opener.document.workform[selected_row].value  = this.cells[0].innerHTML;"

However it is saving the data only in the first cell/column of the selected row.

How do I pass the values to all the cell/columns of the selected row from child window to parent window.?

Comment: I assume that `this` corresponds to the individual row rather than the whole table. In that case you'll want to loop over the cells. However, it would help to showcase both your HTML and JavaScript in a minimal example.

Comment: <script>
   var url=window.location.href;
   var s1=url.split("row_id=")[1];
    var s2=url.split("sku=")[1];
    var row_id2=url.split("row_id=")[2];
                  var table = document.getElementById('table');

                 for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
                  {
                      table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                      {
                                                   
                          opener.document.workform[s1].value  = this.cells[0].innerHTML;

                      };
                  }
           </script>

Comment: This is the code I am using